# How much voltage and amps for 2 SG90 servos?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, voltage-level

Question is pretty straight forward: How much amps and voltage do I need for 2 SG90 servos? I want to use 4 but you might already know that Arduino Uno only has 2 5V ports.

Comment: `Arduino Uno only has 2 5V ports` ... no ... the arduino has one power regulator ... the 5 V pins are both connected together

Answer (score 1):

The SG90 servo datasheet is here:

[SG90 Servo Datasheet](http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/DE1_EE/stores/sg90_datasheet.pdf)

As you can see, the voltage specification is 4.8 - 6.0 Volts.  But you do NOT want to power this or any other servo via the Arduino.  Servos are quite "noisy" electrically and this can cause instabilities with your Uno.

You want to supply power to the servo directly from a +5V power supply.

I don't see the current draw for this servo specified so you will need to do your own measurements based on the loading of the output shaft.  Be aware that these draw more current with increased load on the shaft.

As far as the control signal, the Arduino Uno can certainly drive it via its PWM outputs.

Comment: I know that I am suppose to feed the 2 servos directly from external power source but I still don't know how much voltage and current I need.

Comment: @YağızAlpErsoy, hobby servos aren't typically specified that well. The suggestion that your measure them yourself is a good one.

Comment: These are relatively low-powered servos.  The voltage is specified, use 5 Volts.  A common 5V 1A supply will likely do well here since you are just driving two servos + your Uno.

Comment: @jwh20 thank you! that's it!